# Cross-device passkeys are not working on Android

Tags: android, fido, passkey

I'm trying to create a passkey on https://webauthn.io/ using the following parameters:

- User Verification: Required
- Discoverable Credential: Required
- Attachment: All supported
- Attestation: None

I use the website on a Windows 11 23H2 (tested as well on Windows 10 22h2) and I create the passkey on a Android device (with Google Password Manager). If I try to use the passkey created on the same device, everything works.

But if I try to use the passkey on another Android device (the passkey is properly synchronized between them), I got the following error:

[image: Passkeys]

And a sign-in failed error on the second Android device.

I tried also on several other "demo" websites and got the same error. All tested websites are not using the devicePubKey extension.

Any idea why I cannot use the synchronized passkey on the second device (while the synchronization looks ok)?

Comment: It's a Windows problem. I have this issue on my Windows PC only. 
See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/failed-to-login-by-passkey-using-android-device-on/b3208f02-fdc3-451f-af61-752c16305b25

Answer (score 1):

I have recently discovered a similar problem... I was trying to use the fingerprint reader on an oppo find x2 pro (now android 13) to provide the passkey and always had this reply (on different versions of chromium on linux, chromium and edge on windows ... and no joy with firefox anyway)

It turns out that this device seems not to meet the requirements for one or another reason... I can go back with an older phone (android 9) without any problem.

So the answer might be: your device may not be acceptable...

Which immediately leads to the question: Any idea why this would be? Is there any settings on the phone that would make it compliant?

[This is a web-based example demonstrating the process --- it used to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1h1O.png)

Comment: Same with LG phones. And oneplus