# Android not working as cross platform authenticator

Tags: android, webauthn, passkey

Tested using various sites like webauthn.me,

Similar to this question (same error message), but different [Cross-device passkeys are not working on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77416931/12285843)

LG phone latest updates (android 12), also tested on Oppo and I believe OnePlus has the same thing (various Android versions). Android as roaming authenticator closes connection to webpage when screenlock is requested to create/get a credential. Samsung Galaxy works.

Adb gives me this:

02-14 14:07:24.590 18293 10103 E Fido : [TunnelTransport] errors from websocket [CONTEXT service_id=287 ] 02-14 14:07:24.590 18293 10103 E Fido : atjh: IO Error 02-14 14:07:24.590 18293 10103 E Fido : at atjj.a(:com.google.android.gms@240315038@24.03.15 (190400-601117972):277) 02-14 14:07:24.590 18293 10103 E Fido : at atjd.run(:com.google.android.gms@240315038@24.03.15 (190400-601117972):557) 02-14 14:07:24.590 18293 10103 E Fido : at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012) 02-14 14:07:24.590 18293 10103 E Fido : Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket is closed 02-14 14:07:24.590 18293 10103 E Fido : at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket$SSLInputStream.read(:com.google.android.gms@240315038@24.03.15 (190400-601117972):15) 02-14 14:07:24.590 18293 10103 E Fido : at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:203) 02-14 14:07:24.590 18293 10103 E Fido : at atjj.d(:com.google.android.gms@240315038@24.03.15 (190400-601117972):3) 02-14 14:07:24.590 18293 10103 E Fido : at atjj.a(:com.google.android.gms@240315038@24.03.15 (190400-601117972):10) 02-14 14:07:24.590 18293 10103 E Fido : ... 2 more 02-14 14:07:24.590 18293 10103 I Fido : (REDACTED) [HybridCtap2Processor] On error: %s 02-14 14:07:24.590 18293 10103 I Fido : (REDACTED) [HybridAuthenticator] Hybrid authenticator completed with error: %s

What is very strange is that in one instance of MS Edge launched from VS 2k22 I was able to consistently avoid the issue, except the android experience was different in that a push notification was sent to the device that needed user attention, instead of it just launching straight into connecting to the web page.

Android as roaming authenticator does not work on most requested tests.

Answer (score 1):

This was due to an interop issue between Play Services and the OnePlus biometric prompt. I filed a bug with Google for the same issue: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/41496859. The issue has been fixed and the fix should roll out in the next few weeks.